# Get a text block from a url

Tags: php

forexample, I have this url:

`http://adstorage.jamba.net/storage/view/325/0/fa/Fairytale.mp3`

How can I use PHP code so that it returns `Fairytale`. all the things before `Fairytale` and after that `.mp3` should be removed.

the idetifier are `/` and `.mp3` only the `file name` should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pathinfo()` Function

```
<?php
$url = "http://example.com/file_name.mp3";
$f = pathinfo($url);
echo $f[filename]; // File name
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$url = "http://adstorage.jamba.net/storage/view/325/0/fa/Fairytale.mp3";

$parts = parse_url($url);
$path_parts = explode('/', $parts['path']);
list($name, $extension) = explode(".", $path_parts[count($path_parts) - 1]);
echo $name;
```

This is probably overkill, and this thing could be done with a simple regex like:

```
preg_match("#.*/(\w+)\.\w+#", $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pathinfo Function

```
<?php

$url = "http://adstorage.jamba.net/storage/view/325/0/fa/Fairytale.mp3";

$f = pathinfo($url);

echo $f[filename]; // File name Fairytale

print_r(pathinfo($url)); // File Array

?>
```

Comment: Ah, pathinfo, I forgot about that one.  This is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can tryit with:

```
$input = 'http://adstorage.jamba.net/storage/view/325/0/fa/Fairytale.mp3';
echo current(explode('.', basename($input)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in one line, $input being yout url (php 5.4) :

```
$name = explode('.',array_slice(explode('/',$input), -1, 1))[0];
```